# Undefined method `heade' for DealerDetail:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am having trouble when running this, I keep getting error 
.rb:45:in `<main>': undefined method heade'` for DealerDetail:Class (NoMethodError)
What am I doing wrong I have looked around but cant find any solutions help will be greatly appreciated

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

@browser = Watir::Browser.new

@page = [:dealerdetail => "www.google.com",
         :findadealer => "www.google.com",
         :findadealer_results => "www.google.com"
          ]

class DealerDetail 

 attr_accessor :browser   


 def heade

    @browser.goto @page [:dealerdetail]
    @browser.element(:id, 'mainNav').exists? 
        puts 'main navigation bar appears'

    puts 'navigation bar does not appear'

 end


 def footer   
    if @browser.element(:id, 'pageFooter').exists?
    puts 'footer  appears'
    elsif 
    puts 'Footer does not appear'
    end
  end

end


@deal = DealerDetail .new

@deal.heade
```

Comment: You have a space between `DealerDetail` and `.new` for real? The error indicates that `@deal` has been assigned `DealerDetail` (the class, not the instance). Probably because of your funky `.new` statement. Try and fix that and see if it helps.

Comment: Reading of some Ruby books are strongly recommended for you! Why do you add spaces after class name? Once you defined `@page` variable in the `Object` scope, how do you expect you can use it in `DealerDetail` scope?

Comment: the space after class was a typo that isnt in my actual code

Answer (score 0):

`heade` method trying to access `@page`, which in not available inside instance cause you defined it outside the scope.

I suppose you want to define `@page` instance variable inside class:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class DealerDetail 

  attr_accessor :browser

  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new

    @page = [:dealerdetail => "www.google.com",
      :findadealer => "www.google.com",
      :findadealer_results => "www.google.com"
    ]
  end

  def heade

    @browser.goto @page[:dealerdetail]
    @browser.element(:id, 'mainNav').exists? 
    puts 'main navigation bar appears'

    puts 'navigation bar does not appear'

  end

end

@deal = DealerDetail.new

@deal.heade
```

Also make sure you have no spaces between class/object and called method.

`DealerDetail .new` should be `DealerDetail.new`

`@page [:dealerdetail]` should be `@page[:dealerdetail]`

Comment: I am still getting this error message: `heade': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: make sure you copied/pasted the code as i posted it and the error will gone